# How can I prevent insertion conflict when inserting a variable to a sqlite table?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

Hey I'm okay with writing to the table, except unable to check of the data is already there and if the data is then don't write the data and print a value saying that it already exists.

Here is what I have so far

```
def createAccount():
    username = raw_input("username: ")
    password = raw_input("password: ")

    c.execute("INSERT INTO Logindetails(Username, Password) VALUES (?,?)",
              (username, password,))
    conn.commit()
```

Thanks if you can help me, its for my coursework and I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making myself clear, I don't want it to be possible for there to be more than one of the same usernames in one table... so I'm assuming insertion conflict :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the create table statement to the following, sqlite will know that each username must be unique because you're defining a 'PRIMARY KEY', one that *must* be unique:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE LoginDetails
             (Username text PRIMARY KEY, Password text)""")
```

If you then attempt to insert a row into the table with an existing username, an integrity error will occur:

```
IntegrityError: column username is not unique
```

You can catch this (and other errors similarly) using a try, except clause as follows (this assumes you're using sqlite3):

```
try:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Logindetails(Username, Password) VALUES (?,?)",(username, password,))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print("Username already exists!")
```

Comment: Thank you that did the trick, been busy sorry for the late reply.